# Google Play statistics "Active users" show dramatic decrease in June 2014?

Tags: android, google-play, usage-statistics

This is what my "Active users" statistics look like in Google Play Developer Console. As you can see there is a dramatic decrease in june 2014.

[image: Active users]

At the same time, the "Active installs per device" looks like this.

[image: Active installs per device]

What's going on here? Did Google mess around with the statistics in june 2014? I get the same charts more or less for all my apps...

Answer (score 0):

You got pirated?! ;( I am not sure if this is logical conclusion cause i am not sure how Active installs per device is counted/collected.. :S

Answer (score 0):

I think (might be) your account is compromised as i also received a email from Google about phishing warning,

> Please Change your password today, and Read Google Play Security
>   Alert: Phishing Warning

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that you introduced an update into your app around that time, which somehow prevents the 'Active users' statistic data from being collected.

Since The 'Active installs per device' is collected by Google, it is not affected by something being wrong in your app.

Comment: I did post an update around that time, but how could it possibly affect the statistics collected by Google?

Comment: Maybe they are collected within your app (do you use some sort of Google services library?) To be honest, I don't have a clue about this tho.